# Laravel: public function index() {return User::all;} Not displaying data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When I use this code with paginate it works

```
    public function index()
    {
        return User::latest()->paginate(10);
    }
```

When I change to this, it does not work.

```
    public function index()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
```

I'm using Chrome and the Console does not show any error. And the XHR even displays that there is data. But somehow it does not display in the Data Table.

Please help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `return User::all();`

Comment: how are you rendering data?? and how many data do you have??

Comment: You still get no data because `paginate()` returns a Paginator while `all()` returns the collection. Change your Vue: `data.data` does not exist when using `all()`

Comment: Thank you -kerbholz, I learned something new from your comment. Could please direct me to what I can change the data.data. with.

Comment: Please show your Vue.js code where you're hitting the API and accessing response data.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Your comments have helped me answer the problem. I changed data.data to just data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `round brackets ()`.

```
public function index()
{
    return User::all();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a typo. I typed what you typed but still no data.